# Can we call form validate method from action class in struts2?

Tags: validation, struts2, action

Is it possible to call validate method from Action class in struts2?
so basically we want to take control in action class after validating the field like in struts 1 we can achieve in below way :

```
@Override
    public ActionForward saveUser(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        UserForm form = (UserForm ) actionForm;
        ActionErrors errors = actionForm.validate(mapping, request);
        if (!errors.get("password").hasNext() && form.getPassword() != null
...
...
...
```

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: Why would you want to? What's the usecase?

Comment: Usecase is as below : before validation we need to do some preprocessing like setting some attributes in session etc. Then validation need to be performed but we need to do some post validation processing also.So its required to call validate method from action itself.Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not necessary if you have a validation interceptor on the stack. It performs validation and workflow returns invalid result, so the action never be executed.

Comment: Hi, I'm interested to do multiple times the same validation method (i'm controlling with case which part will be accounted) only is working the first time, for me if you have a complete example of your question with Struts 1, will be grateful with you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
public class Login extends ActionSupport {

private String userName;
private String password;

public Login() {
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void validate() {
    if (getUserName().length() == 0) {
        addFieldError("userName", "User Name is required");
    } else if (!getUserName().equals("Eswar")) {
        addFieldError("userName", "Invalid User");
    }
    if (getPassword().length() == 0) {
        addFieldError("password", getText("password.required"));
    }
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

And there is a nice tutorial https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-validation-example-1.html